# Found wp_deregister_script WARNING in redux framework plugin

Tags: plugins

i using redux plugin in into my theme and i upload theme in wordpress.org show WARNING:

redux plugin in theme and admin folder and redux plugin

WARNING: Found wp_deregister_script in admin/ReduxFramework/ReduxCore/framework.php. Themes must not deregister core scripts.

Line 579: wp_deregister_script( 'wpb_ace' );

WARNING: Found wp_deregister_script in admin/ReduxFramework/ReduxCore/core/enqueue.php. Themes must not deregister core scripts.

Line 215: wp_deregister_script( 'jquerySelect2' );

and also show WARNING

WARNING: Found PHP short tags in file admin/ReduxFramework/ReduxCore/inc/fields/raw/parsedown.php.

Line 772: if (preg_match('/^[(.+?)]:[ ]*?(?:[ ]+'\'(['\')])?[ ]*$/', $Line['text'], $matches))

anybody have any another solution thank you reading

Answer (score 0):

Lead dev and owner of Redux Framework here. Use the TGM init plugin to require an install of Redux Framework the plugin. Problem solved. ;)

Comment: Thank You For Suggestion